# How to fix the error begin LocationUpdates?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an App that shows the user's location and other Annotations.

I'm following a Youtube Tutorial to show the user's location.

(If you want to look at the tutorial). here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SayMogu530A&t=132s
(I'm on 18:55 min right now.)

My code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configerLocationServices()
    }
    
    private func configerLocationServices() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        
        if status == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            beginLocationUpdates(LocatioManager: locationManager)
        }
    }
    
    private func beginLocationUpdates(LocatioManager: CLLocationManager) {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    private func zoomToLastestLocation(with coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        
        let zoomRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
        mapView.setRegion(zoomRegion, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Did get latest Location")
        
        guard let latestLocation = locations.first else { return }
        
        if currentCoordinate == nil {
            zoomToLastestLocation(with: latestLocation.coordinate)
        }
        
        currentCoordinate = latestLocation.coordinate
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    print("The Status changed")
    if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: manager) //Error: Cannot find'beginLocationUpdates' in scope
    }
    
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The guy in the Tutorial hasn't the problem.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typing mistake. You have to write the function inside the extension and use the correct parameter name.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configerLocationServices()
    }
    
    private func configerLocationServices() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        
        if status == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: locationManager) //<-- Here
        }
    }
    
    private func beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: CLLocationManager) { //<-- Here
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    private func zoomToLastestLocation(with coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        
        let zoomRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
        mapView.setRegion(zoomRegion, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Did get latest Location")
        
        guard let latestLocation = locations.first else { return }
        
        if currentCoordinate == nil {
            zoomToLastestLocation(with: latestLocation.coordinate)
        }
        
        currentCoordinate = latestLocation.coordinate
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("The Status changed")
        if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            self.beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: manager) //<-- Here
        }
    }
} //<-- Here
```